# Limit upload speed in sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am uploading a document in sharepoint2010 document library by using server object model concept.
I want to limit the upload speed through code.
Can anyone please tell me, How do i limit the upload speed in sharepoint2010?
Is there any option available on document library to limit the speed?
or else provide me any c# code to limit the uploading speed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Limit speed of what part? In case of server OM you already have everything locally, so you can perform pretty much as many (or as little) operations as you need...

Comment: That is how can i achive? can you pl provide code?